# Is Amin al-Husseini's memoir being accurately quoted concerning eradicating Jews?

Tags: quotes, antisemitism, holocaust, amin-al-husseini

A variety of sources are stating that in a memoir [Amin al-Husseini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amin_al-Husseini), once the Mufti of Jerusalem, wrote:

> Our fundamental condition for cooperating with Germany was a free hand to eradicate every last Jew from Palestine and the Arab world. I asked Hitler for an explicit undertaking to allow us to solve the Jewish problem in a manner befitting our national and racial aspirations and according to the scientific methods innovated by Germany in the handling of its Jews. The answer I got was: 'the Jews are yours.'

For example:

[ANOTHER TACK: Fiendish hypocrisy II](https://web.archive.org/web/20010417102529/http://www.jpost.com/Editions/2001/04/05/Columns/Columns.24216.html), Sarah Honig, *Jerusalem Post* April 2001

[Historical Dictionary of the Holocaust](https://books.google.com/books?id=EzBZP92xwUUC&pg=PA122&dq=%22scientific%20methods%20innovated%20by%20Germany%20in%20the%20handling%20of%20its%20Jews%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjXoYScq-jSAhUG2SYKHZR7DEQQ6AEIRDAH#v=onepage&q=%22scientific%20methods%20innovated%20by%20Germany%20in%20the%20handling%20of%20its%20Jews%22&f=false)

[The Gramsci Factor: 59 Socialists in Congress](https://books.google.com/books?id=OvV69F3yLukC&pg=PA114&dq=%22scientific%20methods%20innovated%20by%20Germany%20in%20the%20handling%20of%20its%20Jews%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZ6I3Qq-jSAhWKwiYKHRViDJY4ChDoAQgxMAQ#v=onepage&q=%22scientific%20methods%20innovated%20by%20Germany%20in%20the%20handling%20of%20its%20Jews%22&f=false)

However, I don't know of any primary source.

Is this an accurate quotation of Amin al-Husseini's journal or memoir?

Comment: Much as it pains me to cite [New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2008/09/28/books/review/Segev-t.html), they seem to have the only rebuttal I was able to find so far: "*Hitler’s alleged and highly unlikely pledge to Husseini (“The Jews are yours”) is based on a passage in the mufti’s own memoirs. **But there is an official German record of his meeting with Hitler that contains no such statement***"

Comment: @user5341 That sounds like a confirmation, not a rebuttal, of the memoirs containing the quote.

Comment: maybe the references cited here http://spme.org/book-reviews/book-review-through-the-eyes-of-the-mufti-the-essays-of-haj-amin/ especially reference 16 could help someone answer

Comment: the book https://books.google.com/books?id=5E9cqHh7CjEC&pg=PA260&lpg=PA260&dq=%22befitting+our+national+and+racial+aspirations+%22&source=bl&ots=Z_H1dcw5gc&sig=QDaklUTbxbKO58-gdiMFsHnlT-c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLqcXQ6-jSAhXBPiYKHT2BBa0Q6AEIKjAE#v=onepage&q=%22befitting%20our%20national%20and%20racial%20aspirations%20%22&f=false cites the quote to this May 1947 document https://searchworks.stanford.edu/view/3035588

Comment: oh sorry I misread the question. I thought it was "did he say that" not "did he claim it was said in memoir"

Comment: Whether or not Husseini claimed it, HItler didn't say it, See http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/did-haj-amin-al-husseini-tell-hitler-to-exterminate-the-jews/30556#30556 for the full transcript of their meeting.

Comment: @SIMEL I'm only asking about what his memoirs say, but obviously an in person meeting with Hitler was not the only way to get an answer from Hitler.

Comment: The linked answer doesn't leave much doubt about intentions, whatever the exact wording of their discussion!

Comment: The primary source ought to be Haqa'iq 'An Qadiyyat Filastin (*Truth About the Issue of Palestine*), a series of essays first published in the Egyptian newspaper *Al-Misri* and then published as a book in 1957. You can find it online [here](https://www.loc.gov/search/?in=&q=Haqaiq-an-qadiyat-Filastin&new=true&st=). I cannot read Arabic, but if someone can, the quote ought to appear in the first 20 pages or so of the book.